# select li having images

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want to apply ifixpng function, for li having images , but i cannot select the below image and apply ifixpng function , how can i select

<li style="list-style-image: url("http://images.abbottnutrition.com/Glucerna.com.br-HCP/IMAGES/bullet.png");"> abc </li>

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to have the style in css?

And it's easier to select it

css:

```
.image{
 list-style-image: url("http://images.abbottnutrition.com/Glucerna.com.br-HCP/IMAGES/bullet.png")
}
```

js:
    $('li .image').some_func()

Solution:

```
$('ul li[style*="list-style-image"]').foo()
```

and the html should be with normal ':

```
<li style='list-style-image: url("images.abbottnutrition.com/Glucerna.com.br-HCP/IMAGES/…; abc </li>
```

Comment: oh, I'm soory, when you can use this: $('ul li[style*="list-style-image"]').foo() and the html should be: <li style='list-style-image: url("http://images.abbottnutrition.com/Glucerna.com.br-HCP/IMAGES/bullet.png");'> abc </li>